# Ansible shell module to run commands are not consistent vs bash

Tags: bash, openssl, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run some openssl commands that validates the pri/pub keys in an Ansible playbook but I am getting inconsistent results when run manually vs Ansible.

Here is the snippet from my Ansible playbook:

```
# Do a sanity check on the private key files against the public key pem files to check they belong to each other ------
- name: Do sanity check on the pri key and pub key pem files
  shell: |
    /usr/bin/openssl pkey -in $(hostname).key -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum > hash.$(date +%Y%m%d)
    /usr/bin/openssl x509 -in $(hostname).pem -pubkey -noout -outform pem | sha256sum >> hash.$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

If the run the commands manually in bash (and both pri/pub keys are valid) the hash is the same (as expected). However if I try run the same commands in the playbook the hash results differ. How can this be?

Sample output from manual bash command run (hashes are the same):

```
cfe2a1ae4dea66e86bfb9afb1f6fc5f05812d7967e03342a7ec310d1d685f88f  -
cfe2a1ae4dea66e86bfb9afb1f6fc5f05812d7967e03342a7ec310d1d685f88f  -
```

vs

Ansible (hashes differ even though the pri/pub keys unchanged):

```
cfe2a1ae4dea66e86bfb9afb1f6fc5f05812d7967e03342a7ec310d1d685f88f  -
e3b0c55298fc1c149afbf4a8996fb92427ae41e4649b934dc495881b7852b855  -
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `tee` to a file, as in `... | tee /tmp/x509.pem.log | sha256sum` -- then you can compare what's being fed into `sha256sum` both ways. We'll be in a better position to explain a difference what you know what that difference *actually is*.

Comment: BTW, if you force that shell to be bash rather than `/bin/sh`, then you'll be able to `set -o pipefail`, such that a failure from `openssl x509` will be reflected in exit status rather than silently ignored in favor of returning the exit status of `sha256sum`.

Comment: @solaris why not put those 2 lines in a shell script (and like Charles mentioned, put the `#!/bin/bash` or similar for the shell that you need or have at cmd line. This way you playbook action will look cleaner.

Comment: `cat /dev/null | sha256sum` → `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855` ー looks familiar?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the positive comments. I managed to get it working by using the **command** module and this gave consistent results on the remote boxes. I first created a small script with the commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /etc/pki/p1
/usr/bin/openssl pkey -in $(hostname).key -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum > hash.$(date +%Y%m%d)
/usr/bin/openssl x509 -in $(hostname).pem -pubkey -noout -outform pem | sha256sum >> hash.$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

Then copied the script to the remote boxes and ran the script in the playbook as follows:

```
# Copy the sshValidate.sh script to each box in /etc/pki/p1 ---------------------------------
  - name: Copy the sshValidate.sh script to each box in /etc/pki/p1
    copy:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: /etc/pki/p1/                           # Copy the file here
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0700
    with_items:
      - /home/ansible/sslValidate.sh       # This is the source file

# Do a sanity check on the private key files against the public key pem files to check they belong to each other ------
- name: Do sanity check on the pri key and pub key pem files
  command: bash /etc/pki/p1/sslValidate.sh
```

I did try using the **script** module but that didn't work too well for me.

Thanks.